# Spring boot Gradle make a tar file from the built jar excluding resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I would like to create a tar file out of the built packages in a Spring Boot application. My build file looks like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "${project.name}"
        contents {
            into('/conf'){
                from('src/main/resources')
            }
            into('/bin'){
                from('libs')
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(Tar) {
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    extension = "tar.gz"
}

configurations {
    customArch
}

artifacts {
    customArch file(distTar.archivePath)
}
```

I would like to have a single tar.gz file containing the following directory structure:

```
tar.gz:
   - bin
       - project.jar
   - conf
       - application.yaml
       - anything else from the resources folder
```

However, when I build the pakcage it gives me a tar file containing the source files and a separate lib directory with the jar file. I would appreciate it if you could help me to understand what the issue is. I suspect for some reason the distribution runs before the build so it doesn't have the lib directory available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your target directory structure you should change your distribution closure as follows:
(Note: I assumed that your application.yaml is under resources directory.)

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "${project.name}"
        contents {
            into('/conf'){
                from('src/main/resources')
            }
            into('/bin'){
                from('build/libs')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to build jar file before making the tar file, you should modify `distTar` task as follows:

```
distTar {
    dependsOn bootJar
}
```

Comment: What about excluding resources from the Jar file?

Comment: You can disable processResources task like this `processResources.enabled = false`. This will exclude all the resources from the final Jar file.